# How to automate Uploading A file using webdriver.

Tags: file, automation, webdriver

I am trying to automate a file uploading using webdriver, my HTML is 
 it is of type file.

using firebug i got the id and it is same for textbox and button.

by using this command getWebDriverObj().findElement(By.id("fileupload")).sendKeys("code.txt"); am unable to fetch the result.

does any one faced this type of situation, if so can you please help me.

Thanks
Raghuram.

Comment: That should work. What OS, browser (+version), Selenium version and language (um, that's a dumb question - your code looks like Java) do you use? Any special technology stack on the webpage (e.g. Silverlight, Flash, asp.net etc.)? What happens when your code runs, nothing at all, or does it throw an exception? What would a javascript `document.getElementById("fileupload").value="Code.txt"` do?

Comment: am using windows7 , browser = firefox(version-11) selenium-standalone-server-2.21.0.jar, language = java. using Iframe. Its not throwing any exception. This is working fine with selenium.type command. But i want to know how to use in webdriver.

Comment: If you use Internet Explorer (or any other browser), does it still _not_ work?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you yre trying with an absolute path to the file you want to upload? The Browse window needs an absolute path, not path relative to your current java application workdir.

Comment: Then I believe we'll need to see a minimal test case. Is it a publicly visible site? Can you make a minimal html-only page where the problem occurs? I just tried to make a pge containing a single `<input type='file'>` element and it works as intended - try it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Autois Windows specific only.

Here is a more robust solution:

For this you will have find the "id" of the actual input box (where the path of the file is provided) and then use the following command:

> ```
> driver.findElement(By.id("upload")).sendKeys("/path/to/the/file");
> driver.findElement(By.id("upload_button")).click();
> ```

If you are using WebDriverBackedSelenium you can use:

> selenium.type("locator", "/path/to/the/file");
>
> ```
> selenium.click("upload_button");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If previous method is not working
You can try next chain.
1. Call File Select Dialog by click button (use webdriver method click() or javascript "document.getElementById('id').click()"
2. And send control to Autoit (or something another) and AutoIt will work with File Select Dialog  (type addres to file, click button)
For example:

```
        var Autoit = new AutoItX3();
        const string widowTitle = "File Upload";
        Autoit.WinWait(widowTitle, "File &name:", 10);
        Autoit.ControlSetText(widowTitle, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", pathToFile);
        Autoit.ControlClick(widowTitle, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]");
        Autoit.WinWaitClose(widowTitle, "File &name:", 10);
```

Setup java and AutoIt http://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/